# Show iOS map types w/ mapbox iOS SDK (routeme)

Tags: mapbox, route-me

Wondering if its possible to show iOS map types with the MapBox iOS SDK.

I.E. if I use and MKMapView I can select from standard, satellite and hybrid iOS map types.  I would also like to add Open Street Map as an option.  Of course I cannot user MKMapView to do that.  I can use RMMapView to show an OSM map, but can it show an iOS map?

Biggest reason for this is I would like to stick with one interface.  I.E. if I add a bunch of markers to my MKMapView and the user switches to the RMMapView I would have to create RM markers and add them to the RMMapView.  This creates a nighrmare when  the user creates markers on the different maps and then switches back and forth.

Answer (score 1):

You can't show an "iOS map", which is really an `MKMapView`, inside of Route-Me/Mapbox. They are designed as peers not meant to be used together.

Comment: Is there an alternative?  I am really looking for something like this http://mapstraction.com/, but for iOS not web.  Would be nice to use a common interface to deal with the map no matter the underling implementation.

Comment: Is it possible to hide RMMapView layers (basically everything except markers) such that I can place the MKMapView underneath the RMMapView.  Basically then I can use only RMMarkers but show them on top of iOS maps or MB maps.